# What is the right way to handle multiple returns in a render function in react or react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have the following component in react-native using expo:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { Location, Permissions } from 'expo';

export default class WeatherReport extends Component {

  state = {
    grantedLocationPermission: '',
    location: null,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
    Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.LOCATION)
      .then(({ status }) => {
        this.setState({
          grantedLocationPermission: status,
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.warn(error);
        this.setState({
          grantedLocationPermission: 'undetermined'
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.grantedLocationPermission === 'granted') {
      return (
        <View>
        <Text>Welcome to Weatheru!</Text>
        </View>
      )
    } else if(this.state.grantedLocationPermission === 'denied' || this.state.grantedLocationPermission === 'undetermined') {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>Permission denied!</Text>
        </View>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <View>
          <ActivityIndicator size={100} color="#5D50FE" />
        </View>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

There are three returns in the `render()` two of them return a view for specific values of `this.state.grantedLocationPermission`. But when this component first loads `this.state.grantedLocationPermission = ''` which then re renders to take a particular value. As a result I have used an `ActivityIndicator`(simple loader) to show a loading animation for all other conditions.

Is this the right way to do this? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a mapping of states to components, and optionally a default/fallback handler. Something like:

```
const Denied = () => <Text>Permission Denied!</Text>;
const DefaultHandler = () => <ActivityIndicator size={100} color="#5D50FE" />;

const handlers = {
  granted: () => <Text>Welcome to Weatheru!</Text>,
  denied: Denied,
  undetermined: Denied,
}

const Cmp = handlers[this.state.grantedLocationPermission] || DefaultHandler;

return (
  <View>
    <Cmp />
  </View>
);
```

There's nothing *wrong* with what you're doing. It works.

But applying some general programming best practices will improve readability and maintainability in a number of ways.

Establishing a separate component for each case, more closely adhering to the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle):

1. Greatly reduces the complexity of the `WeatherReport` component's render method, making it easier to read and reason about.
2. Eliminates the need to repeat the `<View>` container for each case. If you ever decide to change the container, you should only have to do it in one place. ([don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), avoid [duplicate code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_code), etc.)
3. Allows you to alter the behavior or output of each case in isolation, without having to go spelunking through a bunch of conditional rendering logic in WeatherReport's render method. Each of these components could be moved to it own separate file for reuse and/or to implement more complex behavior without polluting the WeatherReport component.

   Suppose you need to display "Permission Denied!" in many places throughout your app, and then you decide you need to change it to "Unauthorized!" or you need multilingual support and it needs to say "Zugang Verweigert!" for a particular locale. If you have a single component that renders this everywhere your app needs it, modifying that one component fixes it everywhere.
4. Makes it easier to support additional states in the future. Suppose your permissions become more granular than granted/denied; maybe you have administrative capabilities or you're only allowed to see specific parts of the report. Adding `admin: AdministratorView` and `restricted: RestrictedView` is super easy and doesn't complicate the base component's rendering logic at all.

Again, functionally this does the same thing, but if your app is going to get even the least bit complicated it pays to think about these things up front and code accordingly.

Comment: Thankyou for replying, I see what you have done and it's really cool. But is there any real benefit to writing it your way? Is there anything, in particular, that is wrong in my code that is fixed in yours?

Comment: I updated my answer with some rationale for the suggested changes.